# Communication between OSGI bundle and web application

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, osgi, bundles

I want to build a web application in combination with OSGI to modularize it. But I'm a little bit confused. I build an OSGI web bundle with a simple Hello Word Servlet. It works. But now, how can I create a "complete" web application and not only a Servlet?

For example I don't know how to reference to different *.html files, et cetera. In typical Java EE web apps you have the WEB-INF folder, et cetera. But not in this case. There is only the Servlet.java which generates the output.

So how can I create a "complete" web application and how can it's backend access other osgi bundles I created?

Are there any good tutorials? I find several tutorials which only create the Servlet.

Comment: OSGi is not the latest recommended approach. The latest in thing is micro services . i.e. you split your application in to multiple stand alone java processes (use spring boot to make this easy). they communicate using RESTful APIs

Comment: Bear in mind that the latest "in" thing might not be the best solution for all possible problems.

Comment: @ManasMarthi "not the latest recommended approach" according to who??

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are different approaches available, depending on what you want to achieve. The most favored way right now would be to use the Http Whiteboard approach. In that way you'd register your Servlets as Services and while doing so you still can receive Services in your Servlet itself. A good starting point is to look at either [PAX-Web Samples](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples) or [Apache Felix Whiteboard](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html#using-the-osgi-http-whiteboard).

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the OSGi enRoute tutorials which demonstrate building web applications with OSGi. http://enroute.osgi.org/

Comment: Thanks. I will try this approach at the weekend.